# How to override AngularJs ng-include directive to update HTML tags at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to update dynamically loaded partials HTML tags at runtime depending upon the use cases where it's getting loaded. So I think instead of using jquery DOM loaded events and do some hack after DOM get loaded, why not override **ng-include** directive.

**Example**: I want to add one attribute to all `<p>` tags loaded. That attribute could be custom directive or something else. Suppose I have four partials which contains text content in `<p>` tag. While loading these four partials in animated mode I want to apply one directive that will do animations with these tags and in other mode these partials may get loaded with different animation effect. But HTML for all four partials will remain same.

How to override predefined angularjs directives and Is there any other alternative way available for the same?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. Can you give a specific example and possibly a demo about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Obaid have a look I have updated question with details.